# Restricting folder interaction of a user with root privileges

Tags: permissions, security, directory, root, restricted-access

Often times when creating an Ubuntu Linux image, rather than giving an administrator root access, a new user is created with root privileges.  Let's call this new user "root_2".

```
# adduser root_2
 Adding user `root_2' ...
 Adding new group `root_2' (1002) ...
 Adding new user `root_2' (1002) with group `root_2' ...
 Creating home directory `/home/root_2' ...
 Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
 Enter new UNIX password:
 Retype new UNIX password:
 passwd: password updated successfully

# usermod -aG sudo root_2

# su - root_2

# grep '^sudo' /etc/group
```

Above code - see reference:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-add-a-user-and-grant-root-privileges-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Now suppose you want to exclude interaction of a particular folder, meaning root_2 cannot read, write, execute or view anything with that folder.  Because root_2 has so many privileges, I'm sure there are back door ways to get access to that folder, even if you restrict folder access.  Perhaps seeing indexes that exist of the file system.  Or macros that root would normally have by default.

This seems like a simple question, but is there a way to truly protect the contents of a folder from user root_2?  If so, please be exhaustive as you can for Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Every distribution of Linux has development that is standard across all Linux distributions and some specific.  If I ask broadly, for Linux, or even all Ubuntu versions, there will be too many answers.

Comment: This is specific to Ubuntu.  If I ask for all Linux distributions, I can do so, but I'll need to be more specific.  Maybe I will, but I'd like to ask here first.  My image is Ubuntu, so I'm trying to understand what is there.

Comment: Please add the Ubuntu version this is specific to in your question.

Comment: There you go @user68186

Comment: If you give the `root_2` user unrestricted sudo access, then whatever another user could do (aside from removing `root_2`'s `sudo` access), `root_2` could undo. You could encrypt the directory, but even that only works until you need to decrypt it (at which point some background script or something like that setup by `root_2` could get at the unencrypted contents). The best way is to not give unlimited `sudo` access in the first place.

Comment: 21.04 has reached the end of life, and is off topic here.

Comment: What is the current stable version of Ubuntu now?

Comment: @MacGyver that would be 22.04. as LTS and 22.10 as not LTS. 23.04 is about to arrive.

Comment: That was a typo on my part

Answer (score 5):

> Now suppose you want to exclude interaction of a particular folder, meaning root_2 cannot read, write, execute or view anything with that folder.

Impossible if the files are on that system, And you forgot delete :)
You can use methods to make it difficult but it will never be impossible.

> This seems like a simple question, but is there a way to truly protect the contents of a folder from user root_2?

An admin user (we do not use root) can always undo anything another admin did. Not even encryption can prevent that. All that the user needs to do is catch the encryption key and that can be done by installing a key press catch program (there is one in the repositories.

You can have a special case user that can do more than a normal user but that is not an admin.

> a new user is created with root privileges

"root" means owning the system.

If you do not want another admin to do anything with a file or directory do not store it on that system. And do not connect it to that system if you store it on an external medium.

Comment: Thank you!  You took the easy way out of this one, you little stinker!